# Working of UIGlass Button

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to use UIGlassButton in my program but I don't know the working process of this button class. I am tying to use this the same as UIButton class but it's not working.

Comment: Two site for your references http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIGlassButton http://blog.jpoz.net/2009/05/20/uiglassbutton.html

Comment: I have seen these links but these way's are not working.

Comment: what is the issue in your code

Comment: What isn't working? The better your question the better the answers are likely to be...

Comment: This is a terrible idea. `UIGlassButton` is private and undocumented, which means it can change at any time, leaving your app broken. Please please please please please don't use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a UIGlassButton do the following:

```
UIButton *button = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIGlassButton") alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
// configure button like any other UIButton
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Using `UIGlassButton` may give you problems during review for the App Store though.

Comment: it's working, One more think i want to know how i will change the color of this kind of button

Comment: `[(id)glassButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Answer (score 1):

`UIGlassButton` is an undocumented class and risks AppStore rejection; but you could simulate by grabbing the image of the `UIGlassButton` and using the image to create your own simulated glass buttons.

I've used the open-source [ButtonMaker](https://github.com/dermdaly/ButtonMaker) project for this purpose.